Weather dont show my location
Using weather app (from gnome i think) i cant find my location. I think is weather from gnome. I am using ubuntu 24.04 but before on ubuntu 23.10 the app didnt show my location. Either by region or city. The capital of my country appear but where i live doesnt appear, and many other cities in my country, it seems jus one city in my country
And the app seems very basic, could give more weather information, compare to other platforms like google or windows 11
i dont know if is just me expirence this or what is wrong with the app or platform.
with ubuntu 23.04 i think the app was showing my location
i have installed weatherian app but it crashes before it opens
i installed kde weather and it works but also Mousam app, i like it better Mousam

Sounds like it has never worked why would it work now?

it was working with 23.04 i think

Use another weather app, like Mousam

But even then you are not sure so do not see what any one can do to help you.

You have described your experience. What is your question?

We can perhaps help you better if you are sure which weather application or extension you are using. Generally, most online weather is limited to what is available. Some countries make lots of weather information and location data freely available, others countries don't. Many countries have different online formats. Upstream developers can use your help to find out what's available in your country, and your help to test that it works properly in your country.
